# Bootsnap::LoadPathCache::FallbackScan - cannot load such file -- bindex

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

When I run `rails s`, it throws me `cannot load such file -- bindex` error. I tried `gem install bindex`, it throws me the same error, tried `bundle update` - the same error, tried `gem update` - the same error. I have no idea how to fix this.

- macos mojave 10.14.5
- rails 6.0.o.rc1
- ruby 2.6.1

result of `rails s`

```
app_7 ⮀ ⭠ master± ⮀ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.0.rc1 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
bin/rails: Bootsnap::LoadPathCache::FallbackScan
    77: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    76: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    75: from /Users/sujize/app_7/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    74: from /Users/sujize/app_7/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    73: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    72: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    71: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    70: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    69: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    68: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    67: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    66: from /Users/sujize/app_7/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    65: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:302:in `require'
    64: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load_dependency'
    63: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:302:in `block in require'
    62: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    61: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    60: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    59: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    58: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    57: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    56: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    55: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    54: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    53: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    52: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    51: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `perform'
    50: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `tap'
    49: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
    48: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:37:in `start'
    47: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:77:in `log_to_stdout'
    46: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
    45: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
    44: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    43: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    42: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    41: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    40: from config.ru:in `<main>'
    39: from config.ru:in `new'
    38: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    37: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    36: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    35: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:48:in `require_relative'
    34: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:302:in `require'
    33: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load_dependency'
    32: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:302:in `block in require'
    31: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.8/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
    30: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    29: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    28: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    27: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    26: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    25: from /Users/sujize/app_7/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    24: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:362:in `initialize!'
    23: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    22: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    21: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    20: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    19: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    18: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    17: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    16: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    15: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    14: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    13: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    12: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    11: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    10: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/web-console-4.0.0/lib/web_console/railtie.rb:11:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
     9: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:302:in `require'
     8: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load_dependency'
     7: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:302:in `block in require'
     6: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.8/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
     5: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:26:in `require'
     4: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `rescue in require'
     3: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     2: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:89:in `register'
     1: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require': **cannot load such file -- bindex (LoadError)**
```

The error:

```
1: from /Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/sujize/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require': **cannot load such file -- bindex (LoadError)**
```

Here is my [repo](https://github.com/Zeesui/app_7) on Github

Comment: Please, edit the question and make it readable

Comment: A new app 'rails s' doesn't work.Create a new app,when I run rails s ,it throws me a cannot load such file --bindex error.I try run gem install bindex,it throws me the same error,try bundle update,the same error,try gem update,the same error.I have no idea how to fix this. please help me out.Three thousand times of appreciate for advise.

Comment: I cloned your project from Github, it works well. What is the path to your project on your local machine?

Comment: You mean's this: /Users/sujize/app_7 ?

Comment: I'm new for ruby-on-rails.

Comment: Try to delete tmp/cache folder inside the project

Comment: Run: rm -rf tmp/cache,same error.You cloned the project and it works well,it means the project is well.So,maybe the problem is my local machine?

Comment: Yes, looks like issue is related to your local machine and bootsnap cache

Comment: All of my new project and cloned other people's project cannot work,I don't know what the problem is?

Comment: This project is fine,the problem is my local machine,and considering that both my native rails and ruby are the latest versions.So I tried to degrade rails and ruby, and the problem was solved.Thank you very much,you did a good job.

Comment: Glad that you found the solution!

Comment: I am seeing this on brand new Rails app 6.0.2.1 using Ruby 2.7.0 via RVM