# Unable to run ruby console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, irb

I am attempting to follow a graphql rails tutorial and I'm running into some issues. I'm very new to rails, and generally don't have this many issues. From the research I've done it may be an issue with Ruby 2.6+ however, none of the other solutions have worked for me.

- Ruby Version: 2.6.5
- Rails Version: 6.0.1
- OS: Manjaro 5.3.15

Stacktrace:

```
>rails c
Traceback (most recent call last):
bin/rails: Bootsnap::LoadPathCache::FallbackScan
        74: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
        73: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
        72: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
        71: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
        70: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        69: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        68: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        67: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        66: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
        65: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        64: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
        63: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
        62: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        61: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        60: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        59: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:101:in `perform'
        58: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:14:in `require_application_and_environment!'
        57: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:22:in `require_application!'
        56: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
        55: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
        54: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
        53: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        52: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        51: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        50: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        49: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
        48: from /home/alexis/Documents/rails-tutorial/config/application.rb:20:in `<main>'
        47: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
        46: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
        45: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
        44: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
        43: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
        42: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        41: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        40: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        39: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        38: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        37: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
        36: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/graphql-1.9.16/lib/graphql.rb:86:in `<main>'
        35: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
        34: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
        33: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
        32: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        31: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        30: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        29: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        28: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
        27: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/graphql-1.9.16/lib/graphql/schema.rb:24:in `<main>'
        26: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
        25: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
        24: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
        23: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        22: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        21: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        20: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        19: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
        18: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/graphql-1.9.16/lib/graphql/schema/member.rb:32:in `<main>'
        17: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
        16: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
        15: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
        14: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        13: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        12: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        11: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        10: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
         9: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/graphql-1.9.16/lib/graphql/schema/member/has_fields.rb:2:in `<main>'
         8: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
         7: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
         6: from /home/alexis/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
         5: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:26:in `require'
         4: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `rescue in require'
         3: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         2: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:89:in `register'
         1: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require': cannot load such file -- irb/ruby-token (LoadError)
```

```
>gem list
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actioncable (6.0.1)
actionmailbox (6.0.1)
actionmailer (6.0.1)
actionpack (6.0.1)
actiontext (6.0.1)
actionview (6.0.1)
activejob (6.0.1)
activemodel (6.0.1)
activerecord (6.0.1)
activestorage (6.0.1)
activesupport (6.0.1)
addressable (2.7.0)
bigdecimal (default: 1.4.1)
bindex (0.8.1)
bootsnap (1.4.5)
builder (3.2.4)
bundler (2.0.2)
byebug (11.0.1)
capybara (3.29.0)
childprocess (3.0.0)
cmath (default: 1.0.0)
concurrent-ruby (1.1.5)
crass (1.0.5)
csv (default: 3.0.9)
date (default: 2.0.0)
dbm (default: 1.0.0)
e2mmap (default: 0.1.0)
erubi (1.9.0)
etc (default: 1.0.1)
fcntl (default: 1.0.0)
ffi (1.11.3)
fiddle (default: 1.0.0)
fileutils (default: 1.1.0)
forwardable (default: 1.2.0)
gdbm (default: 2.0.0)
globalid (0.4.2)
graphiql-rails (1.5.0)
graphql (1.9.16, 1.8.13)
i18n (1.7.0)
io-console (default: 0.4.7)
ipaddr (default: 1.2.2)
irb (1.2.0, 1.1.0)
jbuilder (2.9.1)
json (default: 2.1.0)
listen (3.1.5)
logger (default: 1.3.0)
loofah (2.4.0)
mail (2.7.1)
marcel (0.3.3)
matrix (default: 0.1.0)
method_source (0.9.2)
mimemagic (0.3.3)
mini_mime (1.0.2)
mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
minitest (5.13.0)
msgpack (1.3.1)
mutex_m (default: 0.1.0)
nio4r (2.5.2)
nokogiri (1.10.7)
openssl (default: 2.1.2)
ostruct (default: 0.1.0)
parslet (1.8.2)
pg (1.1.4)
prime (default: 0.1.0)
psych (default: 3.1.0)
public_suffix (4.0.1)
puma (4.3.1)
rack (2.0.7)
rack-proxy (0.6.5)
rack-test (1.1.0)
rails (6.0.1)
rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
railties (6.0.1)
rake (13.0.1)
rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
rb-inotify (0.10.0)
regexp_parser (1.6.0)
reline (0.0.7)
rexml (default: 3.1.9)
rss (default: 0.2.7)
ruby_dep (1.5.0)
rubyzip (2.0.0)
sass-rails (6.0.0)
sassc (2.2.1)
sassc-rails (2.1.2)
scanf (default: 1.0.0)
sdbm (default: 1.0.0)
selenium-webdriver (3.142.6)
shell (default: 0.7)
spring (2.1.0)
spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
sprockets (4.0.0)
sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
sqlite3 (1.4.1)
stringio (default: 0.0.2)
strscan (default: 1.0.0)
sync (default: 0.5.0)
thor (0.20.3)
thread_safe (0.3.6)
thwait (default: 0.1.0)
tilt (2.0.10)
tracer (default: 0.1.0)
trollop (2.9.10)
turbolinks (5.2.1)
turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
tzinfo (1.2.5)
web-console (4.0.1)
webdrivers (4.1.3)
webpacker (4.2.2)
webrick (default: 1.4.2)
websocket-driver (0.7.1)
websocket-extensions (0.1.4)
xpath (3.2.0)
yarn (0.1.1)
zeitwerk (2.2.2)
zlib (default: 1.0.0)
```

Please let me know if there is any other information I can provide. As I said I'm new to Ruby and that includes helpful diagnostic information.

Comment: Can you add output of `gem env` to your post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the stacktrace, it's definitely an issue with Bootsnap, and it may have to do with the bleeding edge versions of both ruby (2.6.5 - released Oct 1/19) and rails 6.0.1 (released Nov 1/19).

Seeing this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57053784/bootsnaploadpathcachefallbackscan-cannot-load-such-file-bindex) as well, I would suggest downgrading your ruby versions into the 2.5 bloodline and trying again and if you're doing a new tutorial, I'm sure that even a modern version of rails like 5.6.2 would work swimmingly as well.

Try RVM or RBenv to install multiple versions/switch between them - it'll make your ruby upgrade/downgrade life quite a bit easier.

Comment: Ok I will try this when I get home tonight. Thank you for your help. Also this is the tutorial I'm following: https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/graphql-on-rails-1-from-zero-to-the-first-query They ask for 2.6 but maybe I should downgrade to the 2.6.0~ version they are using.